# Components don't work on JSF locale change

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, locale

I am using locale change with the following code:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale("mk"));
```

The page gets translated immediately but there's an issue with primefaces components.
i.e. in p:inputNumber component ajax doesn't work and the format of the input is broken too. If I switch back to english locale it works fine.
I am attaching the [link](https://gph.is/2FeIxfL)  to the gif file which I recorded to see the issue in action;

Comment: I don't see anything PrimeFaces related in here... Please, like requested in [ask], make a [mcve]. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Since I cannot verify where actually the cause is, I cannot address correctly. The issue is, I am using primefaces component p:inputNumber. And when I do change the locale it doesn't work anymore. Neither ajax method nor value change fires after locale change.

Comment: Wrong reverse reasoning. By 'addressing' things like removing pieces of code, you'll in the end end up with a [mcve] with something that still does not work but contains only a very small amount of code OR you'll have found the cause. All part of debugging

Comment: Solved it by adding
locale="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestLocale}" in <f:view>